# Bokeh plot Unix timestamps, readable tick marks

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I have two lists that I am plotting in bokeh, the first of which is made up of Unix timestamps. I have no problem plotting, but I want more easily readable dates displayed like "02 Jan. 2002" rather than 1010011671. I have tried changing the parameters when the figure is first declared, but the tick marks are not accurate.

I plot with:

```
t_list = [1239621855.0, 1232034716.0, 1265710807.0, 1289241153.0, 1265330842.0, 1267125816.0, 1285046868.0, 1260797722.0, 1270915355.0]
fig.circle(t_list, val_list, color=col, fill_color='firebrick', fill_alpha=.2, line_color='firebrick', line_alpha=.2, size=3)
```

I have tried:

```
fig = figure(title=title, plot_width=600, plot_height=500, tools=tools, responsive=True, x_axis_type='datetime')
```

and:

```
fig.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(formats=dict(
    seconds=["%d %B %Y"],
    minutes=["%d %B %Y"],
    hours=["%d %b %Y"],
    days=["%d %b %Y"],
    months=["%d %b %Y"],
    years=["%d %b %Y"]))
```

but with these I get tick marks that are formatted correctly, but have inaccurate dates. The first tick displayed is 15 Jan. 1970, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: I don't know bokeh, but it would appear to be a matter of precision.  You probably need to multiply by 1000.

Comment: bokeh uses milliseconds since 1970 as epoch time, not seconds. So as Matt is suggesting, multiplying by 1000 should do the trick.

Comment: yep, fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Would you mind posting a minimal, working solution and marking as solved?

Comment: I multiplied every time by 1000 and added the xaxis formatter.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above the underlying type for datetime values in Bokeh is "milliseconds since epoch" which is why the factor of 1000 is needed.

Also, please note, the formats dict has been replaced by individual properties on the tick formatter, and the requirement to set values as lists has been relaxed. In more recent versions of Bokeh, the above should be written:

```
fig.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(
    seconds="%d %B %Y",
    minutes="%d %B %Y",
    hours="%d %b %Y",
    days="%d %b %Y",
    months="%d %b %Y",
    years="%d %b %Y"
)
```